# extract href in jmeter with Regular Expression Extractor?

Tags: regex, jmeter

After a Successful Login my page contains a Tab "Offers".Link is provided below I want to know how Regex can extract it.

```
 a href="/Offers/OfferApproval"> Offers<a/>
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly

Comment: Question is edited please review

Comment: So you want to extract "Offers" out of "/Offers/OfferApproval". Am i right?

Comment: No, Sir this a href link for my "Offers" page.When user click on the "Offers" Tab this href is hit at the back on HTML & it takes him to the offers page with the help of this href how can I Extract this link to pass it on to the new Request which is going to be the GET request.I hope this could be clear now?

Answer (score 0):

This is required regex for extracting /Offers/OfferApproval value,

```
href="(.+)"> Offers<a/>
```

Use Regular expression post processor.

Comment: It's still giving me this error.                                    [GET http://"No URL"/
[no cookies]]

Comment: I have just shown you way to extract the value. This error represents something different. Have a look at value before getting passed to next request. If it is correct then some other parameters or settings are required for this url.